# How would a demonic pact for home, and deceased wife and child work?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, hunter-the-vigil, demon-the-descent

I've just wrapped up-ish the back story of a character. The story is that his wife and child were killed by a Strix (he doesn't know the Strix part yet), on his Hunt a Demon is going to offer him a pact to basically "bring him the Monster", in exchange I was thinking of asking for his farm, and maybe his wife and child.

If he signs off on all those things, does he remember having them? I know the world forgets. Where does the world think he's been? If he signs away his home, where does he live? Would the pact perhaps just take effect as a normal sale of the farm in reality (if I don't have him sign off on the wife and child part) or would the demon always have owned it? Would a pact of this scale require his soul, or just a piece of it (it wouldn't include his extended family)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The character remembers making the deal, but the world forgets. If he tries to argue that he ever had the farm, or the dead wife and child, he is viewed as a raving lunatic, because everybody Knows that the demon always owned that farm, and tragically lost his wife and kid a little while back. Why is the character being so cruel to that poor man?

As far as the world is concerned... he lives somewhere nearby. Obviously he does, or he wouldn't have been around so frequently. Afraid I'm not sure where he lives, though. That man never invited me over to his place. We've always met at my place to watch the game on Sundays.

He would have to find a new place to live. He is, after all, giving up a part of his life in exchange for the demon's aid.

The only time that a soul becomes involved is when a Soul Pact is invoked. In this case, the demon is taking little pieces of Reality and rewriting them so that the demon takes the character's place.

Comment: after signing the pact would he need to buy himself a new home? or would that history generate itself?

Comment: edited my answer to address that. He does need to find a new place for him to live.

Comment: The world doesn't forget. Only 'directly-affected parties,' the named people given over to the demon in the pact, have their memories rewritten. This inconsistency is one of the key potential hooks that can threaten a demon's safety if anyone investigates too closely.

Answer (score 1):

It's not true that the entire world forgets reality as it was before the pact. Only those *directly affected* by it (not counting the pactbound) have their memories altered.

> The demon and the human both remember reality as it
>   “really” is, but other directly-affected parties simply remember
>   the demon as having always been involved in their lives with no
>   recollection of the person she replaced.

In this case, that would only include the (dead) wife and son. So unless their ghosts, or maybe the spirit personification of the house itself, are spoken to at some point, effectively no one will have had their memories altered by the pact.

As the example given in the book demonstrates, objective evidence is altered, or at least some of the most obvious evidence is, depending. Prominent family photos on the walls of the house now show the demon in them instead, and family albums in the attic might or might not also be edited. Analogous to how personal relationships are rewritten, no new house sale has officially occurred, but the demon's name is now on the deed to the house anyway: the pactbound appears to have never owned it at all, and records show the previous owner instead sold it to the demon. (Said previous owner has probably never met the demon in his life, and is sure he sold it to the pactbound.)

So friends, neighbors, and any other third parties, who weren't named in the pact as being transferred, are completely unaltered, leaving them to assume "Huh, I guess he just sold his house to this guy. Didn't even put up a For Sale sign." But investigating official records would show a contradiction with their memories.

> When the deal is struck, the demon’s Cover
>   absorbs that relationship – as far as the girlfriend is concerned,
>   she’s been dating the demon all along. Obvious signs of their
>   relationship are likewise altered, such as prominently displayed
>   photos of the couple. Depending on the demon’s Cover rating,
>   things like the old photo albums in the hall closet or the ticket
>   stubs from the play they saw on their first date might not be.
>   Likewise, the girlfriend’s family and friends remember her
>   dating the pact-making (now ex-) boyfriend, not the demon.
>   Depending on the nature of the relationship and the people
>   in question, this might get blown off (“Huh, I guess things
>   didn’t work out with Mark”) or raise serious alarms (“You guys
>   were getting married in March! What do you mean you don’t
>   remember?”)

And a pact benefit of Cover is a completely separate option from the pact benefit of a Soul, there's definitely no mechanical need to combine them. There's no limit to how much Cover a mortal can give from his life, even if it takes multiple pacts to wring it out of him.