# Do demons have gender? can their covers gender differ?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

Since a demon's appearance is just a cover (I think?) if, say a female demon (do demons actually have gender?) were to acquire a male's role, would the demon appear male in that cover?

this is only tangentially related to  "[How would a demonic pact for home, and deceased wife and child work?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/51676/1015)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, Demons are above the concept of Gender. Some choose to stick with the gender of their first Cover, but others switch regularly. Depending on the way the Cover was acquired, it will usually decide upon the gender of the demon while using that Cover. Soul Pacts that are triggered to form new Covers are the primary way that gender will come pre-determined.

Patchwork Covers are a little more ambiguous. While it is possible for a pact to include a concept like "gender", it's significantly more confusing as to how that would affect the pact-taker. I would generally rule that the Demon chooses the gender when (s)he does the initial compilation of the Cover.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the story *Thnetosis* in [Demon: Interface](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/134224/Demon-Interface) demonstrates how Covers work wonderfully. I highly recommend this story  if you want to understand a Demon getting Burned and how it can attain new Covers, including a demonstration of the question I asked here.

This is all spoilers for the story, of course.

> Charlotte gives up her job at Starbucks and her ex-girlfriend Robin. “I hope you decide to 
>  be a dude in your new life. It’s really going to confuse Robin and all of her shitty friends if
>  she has an ex-boyfriend all of a sudden, but it’ll serve her right.”
>
>  [...]
>
>  “I live with my two cats in Mr. and Mrs. Caruthers’ basement apartment,” he says, “and I
>  work in the coffee shop on Grand and 15th. Everyone knows me at the Silver Spurs, where
>  I have a beer and watch baseball at least two evenings a week. I once dated a lesbian named
>  Robin Small. My name is Abraham, but you can all call me Abe. My friends call me Abe.”
>  He opens his eyes and smiled at Cole. “And I have the bizarre habit of leaping into Lake Erie
>  on the coldest day of the year. Yes...this will do. It’s a bit scattered, but it will definitely do.”
>  Cole smiles, Charlotte starts laughing, and Alex, finally, lets himself slump down to the

I think it's worth noting that for Robin, there is probably no "all of a sudden",  and it'll probably have been written off as a "phase", or something. This is never clarified in the story.

Comment: In the rules there are comments about situations like that. She (Robin) will be confused as to why the hell she did it but will write it off as a phase (or strange drugs / alcohol affecting her).

Comment: @ThomasE. I feel like I said that at the bottom of what I wrote...

Comment: Ah I misinterpreted your "This is never clarified in the story" part as there is no rules that you are aware of that clarify that. my fault then with the misinterpretion